# How to calculate unique, 3D component vectors from 3D resultant vector knowing the component vector's unique lengths and fixed order?

Tags: vectors

I'm trying to write a program that can calculate a user's 3D finger pose from only knowing the 3D position of the finger's tip and the lengths of the finger's proximal, middle, & distal phalanx.

I'm having trouble finding information or examples of this calculation online with this given constraint.

---

If I have 4, 3D vectors with these relationships and properties:

- A, B, C, R
- R = A + B + C (order of addition is fixed)
- |A| > |B| > |C|

How can I (or can I) calculate the component vectors **if I only know their unique magnitudes and fixed order, as well as knowing the resultant vector** thats formed from the combination of these component vectors?

**or can someone point me in the direction of information that may help me figure this out?**

[image]

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the unique values of $A,B,C$ with that information given, since there are too many degrees of freedom. For example, you can rotate the construction around vector $R$ and although vectors $A,B,C$ will be rotated, their sum and absolute values won't change.

However, you can still try to guess in what “pose” the finger is, by assuming that the angle $\alpha$ between $A,B$ is the same as between $B,C$ and solving

$$(|A|+|B|\cos\alpha+|C|\cos2\alpha)^2+(|B|\sin\alpha+|C|\sin2\alpha)^2=|R|^2$$

which is a quadratic equation on $\cos\alpha$. If $\alpha=0$, the finger is straight. If $\alpha$ is close to $90°$, the finger is retracted. In addition, if you can guess the plane of the finger, you can construct vectors $A,B,C$ in it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "guessing the plane of the finger"?